# Font Awesome 5 Free - far working but fas is not?

Tags: theme-development, themes, css, wp-enqueue-style, fonts

This is making me crazy.

I'm using Font Awesome 5 Free in custom list styles using `:before` and `content:`

In every instance, `far` icons are working and `fas` icons are not.

I've checked everything I know to no avail - any help would be greatly appreciated!

PHP

Confirmed I'm using the latest version:
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started?using=web-fonts-with-css

```
function smart_grid_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome','//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css', false);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'smart_grid_scripts' );
```

SCSS

Confirmed I'm using the right content. And have font-weight set per documentation.

```
// far fa-calendar-alt
li.smart-date:before {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free'; 
    content: '\f073';
} 
// fas fa-link
li.smart-link:before {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free'; 
    content: '\f0c1';
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

HTML

Confirmed no typos, etc. in my classes.

```
<ul class="smart-list">
    <li class="smart-date">far fa-calendar-alt NOT working</li>
    <li class="smart-link">fas fa-link WORKING</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This looks like a pure HTML/CSS issue, you should consult the fontawesome docs, if `far` icons are working then clearly the CSS is loading, and the WP side of things has been done and completed. It is not a WP problem, and WP knowledge will not be helpful to your problem.

Comment: the only difference I can see between them is that in the working one you state: font-weight: 900; just a try..